# Appending node from an existing XML file onto a new XML document

Tags: xml, powershell

I am currently working on versioning functionality for some XML files that I'm working with. The basic workflow is that as an XML file is parsed, it's broken up by Order and then put into a database table, then extracted based on the most recent version of the XML and reassembled into an object that I can work with.

This is an example of what an order looks like as XML (You can just skim through this - this is just what I'm working with):

```
<Order IsEmpty="N">
  <OrderNum>13903899</OrderNum>
  <AmtUOM>US$</AmtUOM>
  <CompanyUnit>Y</CompanyUnit>
  <CreatedBy>PenskeTruckLeasing</CreatedBy>
  <Opened>05/01/2018</Opened>
  <Priority>5</Priority>
  <ShopID>DE PERE</ShopID>
  <TaxOverride>F</TaxOverride>
  <UnitID>892</UnitID>
  <Vendor>64657200-7542</Vendor>
  <NonCompUnitID />
  <InvOrder IsEmpty="N">
    <InvType>REPAIR</InvType>
    <PONum>7542-136815</PONum>
  </InvOrder>
  <RepOrder IsEmpty="N">
    <RepSite>FACILITY</RepSite>
    <RepClass>NONSCHEDULED</RepClass>
    <Opened>05/01/2018</Opened>
    <Closed>05/02/2018</Closed>
  </RepOrder>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>001</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>219</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>001</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>AC FILTER</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>PLUGGED</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>REPLACE FILTER AIR CONDITIONER</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>AC FILTER;AIR CONDITIONING, HEATING   VENTILATING SYSTEM;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>14.99</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>001</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>219</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>001</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>AIR FILTER PANEL</Descrip>
      <Hours>0</Hours>
      <LineTotal>14.99</LineTotal>
      <LineType>PART</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID>AF55777</PartID>
      <QtyReqd>1.0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>31.02</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>001</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>219</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>001</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>1</Hours>
      <LineTotal>31.02</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>1.37</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>001</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>219</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>001</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>SALES TAX</Descrip>
      <Hours />
      <LineTotal>1.37</LineTotal>
      <LineType>TAX</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>1</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>010</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>055</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>002</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>MIRROR SWITCH</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>FAILED</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>REPLACE MIRROR POWER DIRECTIONAL CONTROL SWITCH</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>MIRROR SWITCH;CAB   SHEET METAL;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>43.51</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>010</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>055</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>SWITCH,MOTOR,REMOTE CONTR...</Descrip>
      <Hours>0</Hours>
      <LineTotal>43.51</LineTotal>
      <LineType>PART</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID>DTL 15829700</PartID>
      <QtyReqd>1.0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>38.77</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>010</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>055</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>1</Hours>
      <LineTotal>38.77</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>3.98</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>010</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>055</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>SALES TAX</Descrip>
      <Hours />
      <LineTotal>3.98</LineTotal>
      <LineType>TAX</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>1</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>035</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>015</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>002</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>WIPERS</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>STREAK</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>REPLACE WINDSHIELD WIPER BLADE</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>WIPERS;CAB   SHEET METAL;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>3.36</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>035</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>015</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>BLADE,WIPER</Descrip>
      <Hours>0</Hours>
      <LineTotal>6.72</LineTotal>
      <LineType>PART</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID>ABP N82 7622</PartID>
      <QtyReqd>2.0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>23.26</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>035</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>015</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>1</Hours>
      <LineTotal>23.26</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>.61</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>035</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>015</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>SALES TAX</Descrip>
      <Hours />
      <LineTotal>.61</LineTotal>
      <LineType>TAX</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>1</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>042</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>001</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>024</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>002</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>15</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>DECK PLATE</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>LOSE</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>REPAIR DECK PLATE/CROSSWALK AND MOUNTING BRACKETS</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>DECK PLATE;REPAIR DECK PLATE/CROSSWALK AND MOUNTING BRACKETS;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>77.54</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>002</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>042</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>001</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>024</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>002</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>15</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>.50</Hours>
      <LineTotal>38.77</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>017</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>020</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>017</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>LEFT REAR DRIVE TIRE</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>MISSING TREAD SECTION</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>REPLACE DRIVE TIRE(S)-3RD AXLE LEFT</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>LEFT REAR DRIVE TIRE;REAR TIRES;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>46.52</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>017</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>020</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>017</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>1</Hours>
      <LineTotal>46.52</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>034</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>004</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>021</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>034</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>BACK UP LIGHT</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>BLOWN</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>REPLACE CLEARANCE/MARKER LIGHT CAB AND CHASSIS ONLY-REAR RT</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>BACK UP LIGHT;LIGHTING SYSTEM;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>31.02</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>034</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>004</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>021</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>034</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>1</Hours>
      <LineTotal>31.02</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>.33</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>034</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>004</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>021</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>034</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>SALES TAX</Descrip>
      <Hours />
      <LineTotal>.33</LineTotal>
      <LineType>TAX</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>1</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>3.59</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>034</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>004</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>021</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>034</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LAMP,BACKUP</Descrip>
      <Hours>0</Hours>
      <LineTotal>3.59</LineTotal>
      <LineType>PART</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID>TL  40204</PartID>
      <QtyReqd>1.0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>041</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>005</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>041</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>LOW POWER</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>FILTER</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>COMPLETE AF - REPLACE AIR FILTER MAIN ENGINE (INCLUDES BOTH ON M2'S)</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>LOW POWER;AIR INTAKE SYSTEM;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>57.70</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>041</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>005</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>041</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>FILTER,ELEMENT,AIR FILTER</Descrip>
      <Hours>0</Hours>
      <LineTotal>57.70</LineTotal>
      <LineType>PART</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID>AF27879</PartID>
      <QtyReqd>1.0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>31.02</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>041</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>005</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>041</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>1</Hours>
      <LineTotal>31.02</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>5.28</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>041</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>001</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>005</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>003</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>041</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>10</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>SALES TAX</Descrip>
      <Hours />
      <LineTotal>5.28</LineTotal>
      <LineType>TAX</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>1</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
  <OrderSec IsEmpty="N">
    <Billable>Y</Billable>
    <SystemCode>053</SystemCode>
    <AssemblyCode>004</AssemblyCode>
    <PartCode>001</PartCode>
    <WorkAccomplishedCode>013</WorkAccomplishedCode>
    <CompCode>053</CompCode>
    <ActionCode>95</ActionCode>
    <Complaint>PM</Complaint>
    <CompltDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </CompltDate>
    <PTLComplaint>CAMPAIGN</PTLComplaint>
    <PTLCause>REQUIRED</PTLCause>
    <PTLCorrection>COMPLETE OTH KIDDE CAMPAIGN - BUL#50-117 - REPLACE FIRE EXTINGUISHER</PTLCorrection>
    <DelReason />
    <ExtWarranty>N</ExtWarranty>
    <Opened>05/01/2018 11:39:06 </Opened>
    <Priority>5</Priority>
    <RepReason>PM</RepReason>
    <SecComment>CAMPAIGN;EXPENDABLES;INV#:0013903899</SecComment>
    <SectionNum />
    <TaxOverride />
    <WarrType />
    <OrderLine IsEmpty="N">
      <AdditType />
      <AfterMarket />
      <ChgAmt>77.50</ChgAmt>
      <ChgCateg>STANDARD</ChgCateg>
      <ChgDate>05/02/2018 07:56:38 </ChgDate>
      <ChgUOM>US$</ChgUOM>
      <SystemCode>053</SystemCode>
      <AssemblyCode>004</AssemblyCode>
      <PartCode>001</PartCode>
      <WorkAccomplishedCode>013</WorkAccomplishedCode>
      <CompCode>053</CompCode>
      <ActionCode>95</ActionCode>
      <Descrip>LABOR</Descrip>
      <Hours>.10</Hours>
      <LineTotal>7.75</LineTotal>
      <LineType>LABOR</LineType>
      <Mechanic />
      <PartID />
      <QtyReqd>0</QtyReqd>
      <QtyUOM />
      <Taxable />
      <TaxAmt />
      <VendorLine />
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderSec>
</Order>
```

Now, a typical order contains about 60 of these sections when it comes in. Long story short, I need to reassemble the XML out of these sections.

So far I have created the xml object and created the first node (Which these is only one of in that file), which is a VendorInvoice.

```
# new xml
[xml]$Newxml = New-Object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$newxml.LoadXml("<?xml version=`"1.0`" encoding=`"us-ascii`"?><VendorInvoices></VendorInvoices>")
```

I need to append each one of these Orders to the VendorInvoice to the VendorInvoice node, which I'm attempting to do here:

```
foreach($VendorInvoice in $xml.VendorInvoices)
{
    foreach($Order in $VendorInvoices.Order)
    {
        $newxml.AppendChild($Order.OuterXml)
        $newxml.Save($Newxml)
    }
}
```

Doing this, however, seems to not populate anything under the VendorInvoices node:

```
xml                               VendorInvoices
---                               --------------
version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"
```

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong here? This process has required me to do a lot of removing from XML files, but this is the first instance where I've had to build an XML file.

I can provide more information if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example with simplified input:

```
# The input document.
[xml] $xml = @'
<VendorInvoices>
  <Order>
    <OrderNum>1</OrderNum>
  </Order>
  <Order>
    <OrderNum>2</OrderNum>
  </Order>
</VendorInvoices>
'@

# Create the target XML document.
# Add a <dummy /> child element to <VendorVoices>, so we
# can get a reference to child element <VendorVoices> with dot notation below.
[xml] $newXml = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"?>
<VendorInvoices><dummy/></VendorInvoices>
'@

# Get a referene to the new document's <VendorInvoices> element.
$newVendorInvoices = $newXml.VendorInvoices
$newVendorInvoices.Removeall() # Remove the dummy child node.

# Loop over all <Order> child elements of the original document's
# <VendorInvoices> element and add them to the target document's
# <VendorInvoices> element.
foreach ($order in $xml.VendorInvoices.Order) {
  # Import the order at hand into the new document and append it to the
  # <VendorInvoices> element. Note: .AppendChild() modifies the document in-place
  # and *also returns* the new child node; we assign to $null to suppress this output.
  $null = $newVendorInvoices.AppendChild($newXml.ImportNode($order, $true))
}

# Use Format-Custom to print a quick-and-dirty visualization of the document. 
# If you want to save the document to a new file, use, e.g., $newXml.Save("$PWD/new.xml")
$newXml | Format-Custom
```

The above yields:

```
class XmlDocument
{
  xml = version="1.0" encoding="us-ascii"
  VendorInvoices = 
    class XmlElement
    {
      Order = 
        [
          class XmlElement
          {
            OrderNum = 1
          }
          class XmlElement
          {
            OrderNum = 2
          }
        ]

    }
}
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

- Your inner loop has a typo: `$VendorInvoices` should be `$VendorInvoice`.
- You're mistakenly trying to append `$Order` to the *root* (document) element of the target document rather than to child element `<VendorInvoices>`.
- Appending the `.OuterXml` property value - a `[string]` - of an existing element using `.AppendChild()` - which expects a `[System.Xml.XmlNode]` instance - to a different element doesn't work.
- `$newXml.Save($newXml)` is pointless: you need no save operation for *in-memory* DOM manipulations, and if you want to save to a *file*, you must specify an *output file path*; in fact, it is the stringification of `$newXml` - which is the string literal `'System.Xml.XmlDocument'` - that is interpreted as the output filename here.

Comment: @Matt: I've incorporated my previous comment into the answer.